# Freemarker escape regex characters

Tags: freemarker

How do you run this regex in Freemarker ? The `\.` makes the template to crash.

```
<#assign clean = raw?replace('resource.([^\.]+)', 'resource.$1', 'r')/>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `r'resource.([^\.]+)'` or `'resource.([^\\.]+)'`. Otherwise the problem is that FTL strings also use `\` as an escape character (Just like C, Java, etc.), and there's no `\.` escape.