# Remove special characters in freemarker

Tags: freemarker

I have a problem with Freemarker. I want to remove all the special characters from text string in freemarker: "!"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[]^_`{|}~". I tried writing regular expression for this but it is not working and facing some errors:

<#assign s = 'Foo bAr$%,*^%@()":& baar'>

${s?replace('["!"#$%&'()*+,-./\:;<=>?@[]^_`{|}~"]', '', 'r')}

Please help

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What special characters must be escaped in regular expressions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/399078/what-special-characters-must-be-escaped-in-regular-expressions)

Comment: Hi, I tried the pattern: [^"!"#\$%&'\(\)\*\+,-\.\/\\:;<=>\?@\[\]\^_`\{|\}~"\s] on on https://regex101.com/, it works there but it is not working with freemarker, thats why I posted this question. Any suggestions please.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33492200/freemarker-escape-regex-characters

Comment: thanks, I am able to fix this issue now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simplify this solution like this unless there are other special characters you explicitely want to keep:

```
${s?replace("[^\\w]|_", "", "r")}
```

Comment: Thanks for the correction, this is much better.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to remove these special characters after going through:

[Freemarker escape regex characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33492200/freemarker-escape-regex-characters)
I have used below expression to make it work.
replace('[$%,*@():&"^!{}|~<>=""+-./;?_'`#\[\]\\ ]', '', 'r')